# Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 version 4.1.2. stuck and freeze

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, system-freeze

I have Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 version 4.1.2. Lately it freezes very often and only a restart helps solving that.

I ran Factory data reset, but it does not help.

I don't know how to solve the problem. I bought it less than 1 year ago via E-Bay so I don't know who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

As a recommendation, try installing a custom ROM like CyanogenMod 10.1. You won't lose your apps, and this happened to me on my BN Nook Tablet (rooted) and installing CM fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with the S3.  It's believed to be related to a fix Samsung put out post 4.1.2 to prevent "Sudden Death Syndrome" - where the phone would die and require a replacement.  Using different roms has not worked in 100% of cases.  Fingers are crossed that the Android 4.2 release which is due out for the S3 later this month will have a fix for this, there's no evidence this is the case.  It's believed that the problem is memory related, and there are apps such as Dummy File Generator (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.nomunomu.dummy&hl=en) which will fill up the system memory with empty files to try and force some sort of self-correction, but this is also not 100% successful.  Perhaps worth a go, though.